# Handeling errors in the TPL when I am adding threads to a collection

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am working on a Producer Consumer model where each item produced is consumed on a new Task Parallel Library thread and tracked in a `List<Task>` collection.  I want to be able to catch any unhanded exceptions in a timely and predictable manner.  In a loop I remove the finished threads from the collection and was thinking of something like the following but have not seen any thing online about this.

```
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(threadList.FindAll(x => x.IsFaulted).ToArray());
}
catch(AggregateException aex)
{
    //Deal with the exceptions and possibly kill the program
}

threadList.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
```

Due to good error handling in the child threads there should never be an unhandled exception except things like OutOfMemoryException's and the like.  If that happens I want to catch it and die gracefully with logging.

Are there any better options or even designs I should be looking at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach.
I would wait for each task to finish independently, decrementing the list as the tasks finish:

```
while (threadList.Count > 0)
{
     Task finishedTask;
     try
     {
          finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(threadList);

         // More processing if needed.
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         // Handle exception.
     } 
     finally
     {
           threadList.Remove(finishedTask);     
     }
}
```

Note that this way you could catch specific exceptions while leaving others to go unhandled.

As a side note - look into [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx). The threading model and the exception propagation is handled for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I should be able to make this work and looks to be even better at keeping the list clean.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using `Task.WaitAny` in a loop (removing the completed tasks) instead.

This has the advantage of showing you the exceptions *as they occur* (handling your "timely manner" requirements), instead of waiting for all of the tasks to be completed in advance.